# How to build your own pthread_barrier function in c?

Tags: c, pthreads

I (would) like to build my own pthread_barrier function. It should contain the basic functions of the original.

Here is my Code:

```
int size=10;
    
int OSMP_Barrier() {


    pthread_mutex_lock(&mystructmutex_barrier);
    mystruct->count_barrier++;


    while (mystruct->count_barrier != size) {

        if (pthread_cond_wait(&mystruct->cond_barrier, &mystruct->mutex_barrier) != 0) {
            //print std_error
        }
    }

    pthread_cond_broadcast(&mystruct->cond_barrier); 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mystruct->mutex_barrier);
}


typedef struct mystruct {

    pthread_mutex_t mutex_barrier;
    pthread_cond_t cond_barrier;
    int count_barrier; // init. set to 0

} mystruct;
```

The Problem is: It work sometimes fine and sometimes it just keeps running/stocks ..

Comment: Does moving `pthread_cond_broadcast(&mystruct->cond_barrier);` _after_ `mystruct->count_barrier++;` and _before_ the `while` help?

Comment: Nope, now it just keeps running and nothing happens... . It seem it stucks on `pthread_cond_broadcast(&broad->cond_barrier); `now. I made a printf before and after, it just prints the first one.

Comment: A complete program to reproduce the problem would be in order.